# What do we know about Huey, Dewey and Louie's parents?

Tags: ducktales

Huey Dewey and Louie's parents are legendary in the lack of information we have of them. In the new Ducktales, episode "The Money Bin", we find that Della Duck (their mother) was an adventurer who joined Scrooge (and will likely be a plot point in future episode). Amazingly, this is biggest information drop about the triplet's parents since the letter below (1930's):
[image: della duck letter]

And the father is never named as far as am I aware.

So pre-2017 Ducktales, what else do we know about Huey, Louie and Dewey's parents?

(Ducktales TV series is preferred, but any source is acceptable.)

**Please - Nothing from Wikia. I'm looking for additonal info.**

Comment: Well, there are reasons [nobody else talks about him](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-urWJhekEZP0/Vfi2PlIvk0I/AAAAAAAAGmw/mjFjMpKl_fM/s1600/db-place9%2Bcopy.gif)...

Comment: http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Huey,_Dewey,_and_Louie%27s_father

Comment: http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Della_Duck

Comment: @Valorum I know. But nothing from Ducktales

Comment: My wife asked me his question a few weeks ago, and I showed her one of the few Duck Family Tree images available on the internet, and they all either had the father obscured, or present with no name (and also with a different design based on image). My inkling is that we don't know, but someone else with more knowledge in Duck lore might be able to give a better answer

Comment: @Valorum Added a clarification. I'm specifically looking for new info.

Comment: @TheAsh There really isn't any for now. I've added into my answer a quote from the DXD producers indicating they'll tackle this. All we know for sure is that Della is the only canon parent. She's a tertiary character and canon on everything about her has been (no pun intended) loosey-goosey. [A similar Movies.SE question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23227/what-happened-to-the-parents-of-huey-dewey-and-louie) got more or less the same answer.

Comment: [This video from last month](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_3ny317piQ) has some interesting references to the DXD series and what little they've said of Della thus far. It's purely speculation, but he makes a decent case

Comment: @Machavity what about this? https://www.reddit.com/r/ducktales/comments/72byqs/could_della_duck_be_magica_de_spell/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Donald Duck apparently has a sister. Officially (at least now) she is called [Della Thelma Duck](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Della_Duck), but she has also been referred to just as Thelma. She was [originally called Dumbella](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5mWF.jpg) in the 1938 short that introduced the boys.

According to one [Disney comic](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/The_Life_and_Times_of_Scrooge_McDuck) she's Donald's twin sister.

> Scrooge goes around the world making all kinds of business deals, notably including forcing the Voodoo tribe of sorcerer Foola Zoola off their land. In revenge, the sorcerer curses him to be constantly haunted by Bombie the Zombie. He returns to Duckburg and first meets his ten-year-old nephew Donald Duck, along with his twin sister Della Thelma Duck.

[image]

Their father has been left as an intentional hole. There are no canon mentions of him anywhere.

[image]

Note he's not even depicted here in this family photo from a 2014 Dutch comic that depicts Della as stuck in a time warp in space

[image]

There are [hints that the Disney XD reboot may tackle this](http://tvline.com/2017/08/11/ducktales-revival-preview-huey-dewey-louie-parents-interview/)

> But beneath the show’s adorable, big-eyed facade lurks a slew of disconcerting questions, including: Where are these kids’ parents?
>
> “It is something we’ve thought about,” Ben Schwartz, who voices middle brother Dewey Duck, admits to TVLine. “And that question is something the nephews are inquiring about as well. … The characters do wonder where they came from, and they’re very into exploring that.”